# Is there a way to move lines from one place to another randomly?

Tags: processing

Actually I'm trying to convert this JavaScript code to processing code. But got stuck.

```
var leftToRight = Math.random() >= 0.5;

    if(leftToRight) {
      context.moveTo(x, y);
      context.lineTo(x + width, y + height);    
    } else {
      context.moveTo(x + width, y);
      context.lineTo(x, y + height);
    }

    context.stroke();
```

This is what I came up with and I know its fundamentally wrong but there must be a way. If anyone can at least point me in the right direction it would be great.

```
void draw() {
  line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    if(x1 == 0) {
      x1 = width;
      y1 = 0;
      x2 = 0;
      y2 = height;
      line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    } else if(x1 == width) {
      x1 = 0;
      y1 = 0;
      x2 = width;
      y2 = height;
      line(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the nature of your question, it was difficult to assume what exactly you needed answered. For simplicity's sake, I assume you want the Java code converted to Processing. Hence, I will be ignoring what you wrote in your second code snippet.

The Java code essentially does the following:

1. Generates a random number from 0.0 to 1.0
2. Chooses one output based on whether the number is greater than 0.5:

   - Creates a line from (x, y) to (x + width, y + height) or
   - Creates a line from (x + width, y) to (x, y + height).

Here's a sample of Processing code that may assist you in this. This code is very close to that of the Java snippet you provided, as that is what you asked for.

```
int x = 0, y = 0;

if(random(0, 1) > 0.5) line(x, y, x + width, y + height);
else line(x + width, y, x, y + height);
```

When run, the canvas will show either this:

[image]

or this:

[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was looking for.